# When adding Custom Blocks the weight is changed for the rest of the blocks

Tags: 8, blocks

We are using custom blocks very extensively. We are also using block visibility groups and Domain Access. At this point when we make a new block it changes the weight of many of the other blocks at what seems to be random intervals.

Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: Sure. Adding a block in front of others will change the weight of all following blocks. Let configuration management take care of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have blocks that have the same weight, that may trigger a bug where your blocks get shifted. At least, this is something I have experienced with views filters in D7, and I found a bug report here regarding a similar weight issue in D8 with taxonomy terms: https://www.drupal.org/node/941266

Ensure you are able to see the numerical weights of the blocks, and make sure they all have distinct weights.

Comment: I found that Block Visibility Groups was changing the block weights when viewed in a group. Example: if 'Main Content' had a weight of -38 on the main block layout page, and I selected group that changed the weight to -10 in the top position and saved. The 'Main Content' new weight would be -10 on the main block layout page.